# How to get value of input type = file and display it on a dynamically created image?

Tags: javascript, html, input, dynamic, default-value

I have the following code:

```js
function displayImg() {
  let fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload").value;
  let container document.getElementById("container");
  container.innerHTML = `<img src="fileUpload">`
  
}
```

```html
<input type = file id = "fileUpload" accept = "image/*">
<button onclick = "displayImg()">Click to show</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

I want it so that the user can input the file into the file Input field and it is placed into the source of a dynamically-created image upon button click. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
<html>
<body>

<input type = file id = "fileUpload" accept = "image/*">
<button onclick = "displayImg()">Click to show</button>
<div id="container">
<img id="img"></div>

<script>
function displayImg() {
  let fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload").value;
  //alert(fileUpload);
  let image = document.getElementById("img");
  img.src = fileUpload;

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** The `value` property only returns the name of the file so the image should be located in the same folder as that of code.Or if you want to, you can add the path of the file before.

Comment: where is your image location which you uploaded.

Comment: Ok nevermind, it was a typo in my code, and the error is gone, but there is a new error: c:\fakepath\1959305.jpg:1 GET c:\fakepath\1959305.jpg net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: can you show me your code on jsfiddle like this it can be verified.

Comment: Ohh! ok  i got it, it is the issue of the path that you have set.

Comment: To resolve this for now copy paste one image in the folder existing the code and try to upload that by choosing the same file from the folder.

Comment: Can there be a solution though, I don't want the image to have an image from the folder, I would like it to be something that the user enters in the input field?

Comment: Then for this to happen you have to save the image as blob in database.Because read my note in answer.

Comment: Here's a JSfiddle code if you need it: https://jsfiddle.net/1dtLqes9/5/#&togetherjs=rRDam363gJ

Comment: can you change the JSfiddle code so it matches what you are saying, I am a beginner at JS and I don't know what a blob is

Comment: Yes but this answer is correct on when you want the imagebased on a folder for your desired work you will need to create a database and then fetch it and it will then work for any uploaded image from any user.

Comment: And yes if this answer helped you please accept this.

Comment: Ok look i'll explain you.First of all `BLOB` is a type in the database where images can be saved. And the above code is perfectly fine in giving you the image name,now what happens here is `document.getElementById("fileUpload").value` fetches the `value` of the  uploaded media (which perfers to name) and at the end we set that name in the file `src` which we want to display in the `div` field.In short its just that this is perfect within a limit of your on PC.

Comment: Ok, I marked your answer as correct as you did answer what I was asking, but please do consider looking at this here as I assume you have some knowledge of this field and you can help. Cheers! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61296815/how-to-get-value-of-input-type-image-and-display-it-on-image

Answer (score 0):

please use the below code:

```js
var uploadedFileURL;

function handleFile() {
  var fileUploadControl = document.getElementById('fileUpload');

  var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
  if (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
      uploadedFileURL = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }

}

function displayImg() {
  var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload").value;
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.innerHTML = `<img src="${uploadedFileURL}">`;
}
```

```html
<input id="fileUpload" type="file" onchange="handleFile()" accept="image/*" />
<button onclick="displayImg()">Click to show</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```