# How to get value of input type = image and display it on image?

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for an example where the value of the `<input type="file">` can be stored into a variable and then from there stored into `localStorage` so it is not lost when the page is refreshed, and I couldn't find the solution for what I was looking for.

```js
function myFunction() {

  //Get value of input type file
  let userInput = document.getElementById("uploadImage").value;

  //Store value into LocalStorage
  localStorage.setItem("image", JSON.stringify(userInput))
}

// Display "image" in Local storage as src of img preview even after page refreshes
document.getElementById("imagePreview").setAttribute("src", JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("image")))
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="uploadImage">
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">
  Submit Picture
</button>
<br>
<img id="imagePreview">
```

To summarize, I want to know how to save the input value into a variable, then the variable into the local storage. Finally, display the localStorage in an image tag so it is not lost when the page is refreshed. Please let me know if you have any questions as I know it might be a bit confusing. Here's a jsFiddle as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/vedt_/zrvuwbj7/44/#&togetherjs=gbLynsQ627 feel free to edit it if you know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the image into `base64` and store it as follows:

```js
function myFunction() {
     const file = document.querySelector('#uploadImage').files[0];
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     reader.onload = function () {
     localStorage.setItem("image", reader.result);
     document.getElementById("imagePreview").setAttribute("src", localStorage.getItem("image"))
     };
}
if(localStorage.getItem("image"))
     document.getElementById("imagePreview").setAttribute("src", localStorage.getItem("image"))
```

```css
img {
 max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="uploadImage"><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit Picture</button><br>
<img id="imagePreview">
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use FileAPI to read the uploaded file's contents.
So you read it, then its contents to base64 and finally you can store them in the localStorage.

Also you need to create a `<canvas>` element to convert the image to base64.
Here is your code:
HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="uploadImage">
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">
  Submit Picture
</button>
<br>
<img id="imagePreview">
```

CSS:

```
img {
   max-width: 300px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}

document.getElementById("uploadImage").addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (document.getElementById('uploadImage').files && document.getElementById('uploadImage').files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#imagePreview').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('uploadImage').files[0]); // convert to base64 string
  }
});

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});

function myFunction() {
   bannerImage = document.getElementById('imagePreview');
   imgData = getBase64Image(bannerImage);
   localStorage.setItem("imgData", imgData);
}
```

Here is a living demo: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/rNOLJya